# Dash scatter plot is not updating when the dropdown change

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

Im trying to code an Scatterplot using Plotly and making it interactive trhough Dash callbacks, the issue is that my graph is not updating when I change the dropdown list. the data structure is the following:

periodo Direccion   fecha_rep   revisados   errores
202002  Dir5      29/02/2020       16793        3
202001  Dir5      31/01/2020       18933        1
202101  Dir5      31/01/2021       6246        132
202001  Dir4      17/01/2020        13          1

```
#Importar librerías
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

#Carga de datos
df_temp = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\Datos_maestros\periodo.xlsx')

app = dash.Dash()
fechas = []
for fecha in df_temp['periodo'].unique():
    fechas.append({'label': str(fecha), 'value': fecha})

#Definición del layout de la app a partir de componentes HTML y Core
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph_line'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='selector_fecha', options = fechas, value = '') #Seleccionamos todo el rango de fechas de nuestro dataframe
])

# CREACIÓN DE GRÁFICOS E INTERACTIVIDAD
#Callback para actualizar gráfico en función del rango de fechas seleccionadas
@app.callback(Output('graph_linea', 'figure'),
              [Input('selector_fecha', 'value')])
def actualizar_graph(fecha):
    filtered_df = df_temp[df_temp['periodo'] == fecha]
    #Creación de 1 traza por cada ciudad de nuestro dataframe
    traces = []
    for nombre_area in filtered_df['Direccion'].unique():
        df_area = filtered_df[filtered_df['Direccion'] == nombre_area]
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            x=df_area['revisados'],
            y=df_area['errores'],
            text=df_area['Direccion'],
            mode='markers',
            opacity=0.7,
            marker={'size': 15},
            name=nombre_area
        ))
    
        return { #Se retornan los objetos data y layout para ser enviados al Output con identificador graph_linea
            'data': traces,
            'layout': go.Layout(
                xaxis={'title': 'Fecha'},
                yaxis={'title': 'Errores'},
                hovermode='closest'
            )
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=5000)
```

Comment: Is your return statement inside that `for` loop? Take it out, if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this does not always work, but for future questions try to refactor your problem into a reproducible example. Meaning a piece of code that each of us can reproduce. This makes it a lot easier for us to help you since we can't run your code because of the missing missing .xslx file.

That said, I think there are two main problems. As @coralvanda already mentioned it is weird that your `return` statement is inside the for loop. I assume you should pull it out there unless you intend to stop the loop after the first iteration. Second, updating a plotly graph involves a figure object. Have a look at [go.Figure()](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html). Add the figure object first, then add your desired traces. The fixed code could look like this:

```
#Importar librerías
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

#Carga de datos
df_temp = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\Datos_maestros\periodo.xlsx')

app = dash.Dash()
fechas = []
for fecha in df_temp['periodo'].unique():
    fechas.append({'label': str(fecha), 'value': fecha})

#Definición del layout de la app a partir de componentes HTML y Core
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph_line'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='selector_fecha', options = fechas, value = '') #Seleccionamos todo el rango de fechas de nuestro dataframe
])

# CREACIÓN DE GRÁFICOS E INTERACTIVIDAD
#Callback para actualizar gráfico en función del rango de fechas seleccionadas
@app.callback(Output('graph_linea', 'figure'),
              [Input('selector_fecha', 'value')])
def actualizar_graph(fecha):
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    filtered_df = df_temp[df_temp['periodo'] == fecha]
    #Creación de 1 traza por cada ciudad de nuestro dataframe
    traces = []
    for nombre_area in filtered_df['Direccion'].unique():
        df_area = filtered_df[filtered_df['Direccion'] == nombre_area]
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=df_area['revisados'],
                y=df_area['errores'],
                text=df_area['Direccion'],
                mode='markers',
                opacity=0.7,
                marker={'size': 15},
                name=nombre_area
            )
        )
    
    fig['layout'] = go.Layout(
        xaxis={'title': 'Fecha'},
        yaxis={'title': 'Errores'},
        hovermode='closest'
    )
    
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=5000)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!